# Firebase Dynamic Link Url patterns

Tags: regex, firebase-dynamic-links, url-pattern, re2-syntax

I need to add url patterns for a domain that has multiple subdomains in the Url.

**For example:**

`https://demo.site1.mybrand.company/` Where `.company` is the top-level domain and `mybrand` is the domain.

The problem is that the `demo` subdomain can change based on the environment in the app, so it could be **demo**, or **test**, or anything, so I would like to make sure that any subdomain with `site1.mybrand.company` can access the Dynamic Links API and generate links for that Url.

**What I have tried:**

Firebase docs cite that these are too permission and I am not sure if Firebase supports multi-tier domains such as this.

- `^https://.*.company/.*$`
- `^https://.*.mybrand.company/.*$`
- `^https://.*.site1.mybrand.company/.*$`

Has anyone experienced this situation before or know if this particular scenario is supported?

**References:**

- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429
- https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Answer (score 3):

You might use a bit more specific pattern to match either demo or test using an alternation, and extend that to all the allowed names.

```
^https://(?:demo|test)\.site1\.mybrand\.company/\S*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `https://` Match literally
- `(?:demo|test)` Match either `demo` or `test`
- `\.site1\.mybrand\.company/` Match `.site1.mybrand.company/` (note to escape the dot)
- `\S*` Match optional non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xAHqxm/1)

Comment: What if I need to `(?:demo|test)` to be anything?

Comment: @WrightsCS you can specifiy what you would allow. You can match 1 or more word characters using `\w+` like `^https://\w+\.site1\.mybrand\.company/\S*$` or you can use a more broader match for any non whitespace character except for a dot like `^https://[^\s.]+\.site1\.mybrand\.company/\S*$`

Comment: In regex101 these work great and the Urls are matching, but in firebase allowlist, these Urls still arent working

Comment: @WrightsCS Did you try double escaping the backslash? `^https:\\/\\/[^\\s.]+\\.site1\\.mybrand\\.company/\\S*$`

Comment: no, I might have to try that later